# In how many ways n unlabelled balls can be distributed in m labelled boxes with capacities $c_1, ..., c_m$, where $c_1+...+c_m\geq n?$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $n$ unlabelled balls and m labelled boxes $B_1, ..., B_m$. For each $i=1,...,m$, capacity of $B_i$ is $c_i$. In how many way we can distribute these balls in the boxes?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. What have you tried already? Where are you struggling? The likelihood of a good answer will increase significantly if you show your efforts.

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with the [mathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  In fact, given how difficult this problem is for someone new to the pertinent topics, I regard the protocol as *ridiculous*.  However, there isn't anything that I can do about it, other than provide you with directional guides. ...see next comment

Comment: Assuming that you are untrained in attacking this problem with *generating functions*, then the standard approach is to combine using [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) with [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Let $R = $ the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_m = n ~: ~x_1, \cdots, x_m  \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$ and let $S = $ the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_m = (n - c_1 - 1) ~: x_1, \cdots, x_m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.  Then $R - S = $ the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_m = n ~: ~x_1, \cdots, x_m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~x_1 \leq c_1$.

Comment: Let $c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_m=C$. Let $b_1, \cdots, b_m$ be a possible distribution of $n$ balls in the boxes. That is $b_1+ \cdots + b_m=n$ and $b_i\leq c_i$ for each $i$, $1\leq i\leq m$. Then, 
$$
 C= (c_1-b_1) + (c_2-b_2) + \cdots + (c_m-b_m) + n. 
$$
Let  $a_i=(b_i - c_i)$ for each $i$, $1\leq i\leq m$. Therefore, existing $b_1, \cdots, b_m$ with the above properties is equal to existing $a_1, \cdots, a_m$ such that $a_1+ \cdots +a_m= C-n$ and $a_i\geq 0$ for each $i$, $1\leq i\leq m$. The number of all possibilities to these sets of integers is 
$$
{C-n+m-1
\choose
m-1}.
$$

Comment: The comment posted on October 5 by me is not a correct solution.